# Non Constant Coefficients PDE (part of solving a differential equation using symmetry methods)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How would I solve: 
$$ y^3 \eta_{xx} - y \eta_x =0 $$
where $\eta(x,y)$

I started by dividing by $y^3$ to get: $$ \eta_{xx} - \frac{1}{y^2}\eta_x = 0$$

I then thought to let $u = \eta_x$ and then rewrite my problem as:
$$ u_x - \frac{1}{y^2} u = 0$$ but this doesn't seem correct.  This method (i think) will only work if $u$ is a function in $x$ only and if the coefficient is also a function in $x$.  Having the coefficient a function in $y$ and my function in $(x,y)$ is what is confusing me.

:(

Please help.

NOTE: this PDE arises from a system of PDEs found when solving a differential equation using symmetry methods.  The preamble to it all is quite lengthy, essentially I get 4 PDEs which I use to determine $\eta(x,y)$ and $\ni(x,y)$.

The list of PDEs I get are as follows:
$$ 2\eta - y\xi_x + 2y^3\eta_{xy} - y^3\xi_xx = 0 $$
$$ -2y\xi_y + y^3\eta_{yy} - 2y^3\xi_{xy} = 0 $$
$$ -y\eta_x + y^3\eta_{xx} = 0 $$
$$ y^3\xi_{yy} = 0$$

From the last equation I get: $\xi(x,y) = A(x)y + B(x)$

When I have solved for $\xi$ and $\eta$ they will then give me the Generator for the Lie Symmetries.

The notes where I found this example use MAPLE software to solve the PDEs, I need to be able to do so manually.

Comment: Missing from your problem statement is information about initial and/or boundary conditions.

Comment: @hardmath this is not an ivp or bvp question.

Comment: Maybe you should state the problem to be solved.  Obviously the PDE by itself does not determine a function $\eta$ completely.  For example, if $\eta$ satisfies the PDE, so also will $\eta + C$ for any constant.  I think your approach is essentially correct:  for fixed $y\neq 0$, the "PDE" is actually an ODE for $\eta_x$.  Knowing what initial or boundary conditions are specified will help tell whether this approach is fruitful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that

$\eta_{xx} = y^{-2}\eta_x \tag 0$

may be written as

$(\ln \eta_x)_x = \dfrac{\eta_{xx}}{\eta_x} = y^{-2}. \tag{0.5}$

Only $x$-derivatives occur in the equation

$(\ln \eta_x)_x = y^{-2}; \tag 1$

therefore it may be treated as an ordinary differential equation, with $y$ playing the role of an independent parameter.  As such, and based on its simple form, it easily submits to direct integration with respect to $x$:

$\ln \eta_x = y^{-2}x + C_1; \tag 2$

that is,

$\eta_x = e^{y^{-2}x + C_1} = e^{C_1}e^{y^{-2}x}; \tag 3$

then

$\eta(x, y) = e^{C_1}y^2 e^{y^{-2}x} + C_2,  \tag 4$

which is easily checked; (4) yields

$\eta_x = e^{C_1}e^{y^{-2}x} = e^{y^{-2}x + C_1}; \tag 5$

$\ln \eta_x = y^{-2}x + C_1; \tag 6$

$(\ln \eta_x)_x = y^{-2}. \tag 7$

Here $C_1$ and $C_2$ are of course arbitrary constants of integration.